# Find an instance satisfying equation

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, numerics, variable, constraint

I have the following equation with two variables `xi` and `nu`.

```
funcGamma[m_, delta_, xi_] := 
  1/(m (delta + xi) + 1) + 1/(m - m (delta + xi) + 1);

Exp[-2 m k xi^2/(n + 1)] + 
 Exp[-2 funcGamma[
    m, delta, xi] ((n (nu - xi))^2 - 1)]==e
```

As an example, here are some values for the variables. This is just an example and the values for the variables might change from case to case. I have written the expected range as comment beside every variable.

```
n=10^5;(*n is a posiitve integer greater than 1*)
k=10^-2 n; (*k is a posiitve integer greater than 1 and less than n*)
delta=10^-1;(*delta is a real number between 0 and 1/2*)
e=10^-20;(*fixed value*)
m=n+k;
```

I tried `FindInstance, Reduce, NSolve` with no luck. Note that the equation is to be solved with the constraints given below.

```
FindInstance[
 Exp[-2 m k xi^2/(n + 1)] + 
    Exp[-2 funcGamma[
       m, delta, xi] ((n (nu - xi))^2 - 1)] == 
   e && delta > nu > xi > 0 && 
  m (delta + xi) \[Element] 
   PositiveIntegers && (n (nu - xi))^2 > 
   1, {nu, xi}, Reals]
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no real solution in view of

```
NMinimize[{ (Exp[-2 m k xi^2/(n + 1)] + 
          Exp[-2 *(1/(m (delta + xi) + 1) + 
   1/(m - m (delta + xi) + 1))*((n (nu - xi))^2 - 1)] - 
    e)^2 , delta > nu > xi > 0 && m (delta + xi) == s &&
   s \[Element]  PositiveIntegers && (n (nu - xi))^2 > 
   1}, {nu, xi, s},WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision].
```

> `{3.76882*10^-13, {nu -> 0.0893718, xi -> 0.0841485, s -> 18599}}`

In the above the equation is solved as a minimization problem. The artificial variable `s` is introduced because `NMinimize` does not directly work with  `m (delta + xi) \[Element]  PositiveIntegers`. `funcGamma[m, delta, xi]`  in the target function is replaced by   `1/(m (delta + xi) + 1) + 1/(m - m (delta + xi) + 1)` to speed up calculations.

Edit. `Method->"DifferentialEvolution"` is omitted.

Comment: Of course, `n=10^5;(*n is a posiitve integer greater than 1*)
k=10^-2 n; (*k is a posiitve integer greater than 1 and less than n*)
delta=10^-1;(*delta is a real number between 0 and 1/2*)
e=10^-20;(*fixed value*)
m=n+k;` is executed before `NMinimize`.

Comment: The command of Maple `DirectSearch:-SolveEquations` with bells cannot find even  a feasible initial point.